# When click expand button, scroll fit current expand contents in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

First, I apologize for not explaining well.

When I create multiple Accordion using mui(each AccordionDetails height are 80vh). How can I see the entire content of that selected Accordion?

Thank you.

I attached a screenshot for better understanding and code.

**SOLUTION**
I solved this one using useref and scrollIntoView.

[image]

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

export default function Example() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([
        {name:"hello",desc:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget."},
        {name:"hello",desc:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget."},
        {name:"hello",desc:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget."},
        {name:"hello",desc:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget."},
    ])
     
    return (
    <div>
      {data.map((data) => {
        return(
         <Accordion>
         <AccordionSummary
           expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
           aria-controls="panel1a-content"
           id="panel1a-header"
         >
           <Typography>{data.name}</Typography>
         </AccordionSummary>
         <AccordionDetails style={{height:"100vh"}}>
           <Typography>
             {data.desc}
           </Typography>
         </AccordionDetails>
       </Accordion>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can override the accordionRoot height using `sx` property.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you provide me with how to do it?